# MDADM not assembling raid0 that is part of a raid5 on boot

Tags: ubuntu, raid, boot, mdadm

I use a RAID0 (md2) as a device in a RAID5 (md3) setup (see below). Now everytime the computer boots, mdadm will mark md3 as degraded and i am forced to re-add md2 as a new spare. Of course mdadm then starts resyncing/recovering.

Is there a way to tell mdadm to wait for md2 before assembling md3 on boot time, or another solution to this problem?

System (Ubuntu 12.10 Server 64bit):

```
$ uname -a
Linux nas-server.local 3.5.0-25-generic #39-Ubuntu SMP Mon Feb 25 18:26:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# mdadm --detail --scan 
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 name=lubuntu:1 UUID=70bdbcc1:a423c042:e798e197:56cc4396
ARRAY /dev/md/3 metadata=1.2 spares=1 name=lubuntu:0 UUID=bce57189:aa8ae91a:a1268e87:bef78ff4
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 name=nas-server:1 UUID=fdc6b691:3ca45346:3b493827:8ca7ed4e
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 name=nas-server:0 UUID=3bad2d5c:68517cb9:34631143:27c21bd1
```

Array /dev/md/2 is used as an active drive in /dev/md/3:

```
# mdadm --detail /dev/md2
/dev/md2:
Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Thu Mar 14 10:00:09 2013
Raid Level : raid0
Array Size : 2930276864 (2794.53 GiB 3000.60 GB)
Raid Devices : 2
Total Devices : 2
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Thu Mar 14 10:00:09 2013
State : clean 
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 2
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 0

Chunk Size : 512K

Name : lubuntu:1
UUID : 70bdbcc1:a423c042:e798e197:56cc4396

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
0       8       64        0      active sync   /dev/sde
1       8       80        1      active sync   /dev/sdf

/dev/md3:
Version : 1.2
Creation Time : Thu Mar 14 10:00:49 2013
Raid Level : raid5
Array Size : 5860270080 (5588.79 GiB 6000.92 GB)
Used Dev Size : 2930135040 (2794.39 GiB 3000.46 GB)
Raid Devices : 3
Total Devices : 3
Persistence : Superblock is persistent

Update Time : Mon Mar 18 14:56:49 2013
State : clean, degraded, recovering 
Active Devices : 2
Working Devices : 3
Failed Devices : 0
Spare Devices : 1

Layout : left-symmetric
Chunk Size : 512K

Rebuild Status : 12% complete

Name : lubuntu:0
UUID : bce57189:aa8ae91a:a1268e87:bef78ff4
Events : 25514

Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
4       8       32        0      active sync   /dev/sdc
1       8       48        1      active sync   /dev/sdd
3       9        2        2      spare rebuilding   /dev/md/2
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had a very similar problem.

1. In /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf, place the drives in the order they should be assembled. I did not find that containers was necessary, though I did explicitly list the array in the devices.

   ```
   DEVICE partitions containers /dev/md/2
   ARRAY /dev/md/2 ...
   ARRAY /dev/md/3 ...
   ```
2. Update the initramfs. This was critical to my debian 6 setup.

   ```
   update-initramfs -u
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You realy need such crazy raid setup? O_o

Try adding to /etc/mdadm/mdadm.conf:

```
DEVICE partitions containers
ARRAY /dev/md/2 ...
ARRAY /dev/md/3 ...
```

Keyword 'containers' will cause mdadm to look for assembled arrays as source for assembling futher arrays.

Comment: I found useful same kind of setup when assemble raid from devices with different sizes. 128+128+256. When raid-0 is build as usual - second half of 256 drive used alone -> low speed in the end of raid. When I rebuild it as (128+128)+256 it works much better and without performance loss at the end.